# Retrieving and manipulating interactive PDF document with JS

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I'm working for a friend that needs to manipulate an interactive PDF with the following needs:
there are 2 main "layers" and 2 buttons. When I press button1 only the layer1 is visible, when I press button2, the layer2 is the only visible.

He can upload a javascript for each button with the action that must start on the click, and this is the code I wrote for him.

```
var layerToHideLabel = "testlayer1";
var layerToShowLabel = "testlayer2";

showField(layerToShowLabel);
hideField(layerToHideLabel);

function showField(fieldName){
    var field = null;
    field = FindOCG(fieldName);
    if(field != null){
        setVisibility(field,true);
    }
}

function hideField(fieldName){
    var field = null;
    field = FindOCG(fieldName);
    if(field != null){
        setVisibility(field,false);
    }
}

function setVisibility(field, status){
    field.state=status;
}

function FindOCG(cName) { 
    var aOCGs = this.getOCGs(); 
    for(var i=0; aOCGs && i<aOCGs.length;i++) { 
        if(aOCGs[i].name == cName) return aOCGs[i]; 
    } 
    return null; 
}
```

The `getOCGs` function is a built-in functionality for the document, and of course, when I launch the method I get the following error:

```
this.getOCGs is not a function
```

I think the issue is context related, as the script is launched on the click of the button, so maybe `this` refers to the button and not to the document.

I tried lot of combinations to retrieve the document from the OCG, with no luck. I tried document, $doc, doc, Document, but nothing. I'm afraid it's not even possible, maybe I should try to upload some code at document level, but I don't know if I can add some `onchange` functionality.

This is the guide I've been following so far:
https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/create_use_layers

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not skilled in PDF JavaScript, but when I face similar issues I generally try to get the infos from the event handler.

May I guess you have an onclick somewhere which calls show/hide field?

Comment: The problem is the whole document is generated by a software that "wraps" everything, so I can just put my js code clicking on the button, but I have no visibility of the code behind!

Comment: I see. I guess you have no control over `document.addEventListener("click", myfunction(this))`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'this.getOCGs()', try calling 'event.target.doc.getOCGs()'.

In a function defined in one of the folder-level JavaScripts files, 'this' is undefined. Calling functions should pass the Doc to any function at this level that needs it.

The Doc object can often be accessed through event objects, which are created for each event by which a JavaScript is executed:
● For mouse, focus, blur, calculate, validate, and format events, event.target returns the Field object that initiated the event. You can then access the Doc object through the Doc method of the Field object.